# AFNetworking get progress in another view controller

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Two view controllers: MainVC & PostVC. Click "Add" button in MainVC can pop up PostVC, and click "Post" button in PostVC can post data and pop out PostVC.

Here is the question: How can I get the post progress in MainVC after PostVC was removed? Or is there a way to delay the request after PostVC removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest placing the logic for your `post` method in a different class, that way both view controllers can access properties like current progress, or can receive callbacks via a [delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). This way of thinking about program design follows the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: If I understood right,  I can set the networking-handling-class's delegate to be MainVC, then I could get the progress in MainVC. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

As Evan says, you'd better put the networking codes in a specific class. But if you still want to do it in the controller, you can post a notification when the progress ends, and receive it in the MainVC